# How to return array in C from kernel to user with system call

Tags: c, linux-kernel, return-type

I already did the hard part of adding a system call to the linux kernel. I need to return the following array:
 `unsigned int counts[4]`  
I can reference the array as curr->counts, but I don't think there is a return value for that, and I think it is bad to give a pointer into kernel space?
Instead I'm thinking the best way is to return void and pass by parameter. Is that the way to go?

Comment: tl;dr (i.e., I only read the title ;-)). But, `pipe` returns an array of two, and you may be able to use the same mechanism for your case.

Comment: @Chris There, its short now. I assume by pipe you mean |?

Comment: No, I mean [the `pipe` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html). And, looking at that now, it does use the approach you suggest (except it returns an `int` so errors can be signalled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the kernel routine [`copy_to_user ()`](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/copy_to_user.9/).  Design the system call interface to pass a parameter which is a pointer where to return the data.

You are trying to do something like the `read()` or `gettimeofday()` system calls, right?  Those all return more than 32-bit results by using `copy_to_user()`.

Comment: I am returning the number of processes forked from a pid.

Comment: @Josh:  How many bytes does that take?  Seems like it should be a single `int`, does it not?

Comment: It is a single unsigned int counter each for fork,vfork, clone, and execve.

Comment: @Josh: `execve` doesn't fork, just for the record. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes -- copying the data to a user buffer avoids all kinds of problems.

Comment: @Ernest How do I check that the passed in buffer is long enough? That seems to be the only thing that could go wrong.

Comment: Well, you can't; C doesn't provide any way for you to find out the size of a memory block. Somehow, things generally manage to work out all right though :)

Comment: @Josh: Make the user specify a length, and verify that the whole region is owned by that process.

Comment: The length is always supposed to be 4 ints. What function do I use for veryifying they reserved it?

Comment: Well, you can try to encourage them always have a big enough array by providing a `typedef int return_type[4];` or similar.

Comment: That sounds very good. Could you give a little more detail on this method? The typedef would be in the system call? It seems it would have to be in some sort of util.h that a user would use?

Comment: @Josh: yes, define the data type in a header.